# before_action except: PATCH

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm defining some variables that I need for my header, into my application controller. But I would like to disable it for my AJAX requests. So I would like to know if it's possible to disable a before action for all the PATCH requests. Like on the example below

ApplicationController:

```
before_action :some_value, except: PATCH method

def some_value
  @main_group = current_user.groups.first
  @groups = current_user.groups - @main_group
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check that request is AJAX request, you can use `request.xhr?` method. See the [Rails API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-xhr-3F)

And to use it in `before_action`, you can write something like:

```
before_action :some_value, unless: -> { request.xhr? }
```

Comment: Cool, thanks @PetrBalaban, that was exactly what I'm looking for. Good continuation !!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there's a way to define that on `before_action` declaration, but guess you could check on your method for `request.patch?`, like this:

```
def some_value
  if !request.patch?
    @main_group = current_user.groups.first
    @groups = current_user.groups - @main_group
  end
end
```

Hope this helps, good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RonanLopes ! PetrBlaban gave me exactly what i'm looking for. But thanks anyway, good continuation